# Wechaty: possible to re-trigger login on logout event?

Tags: wechaty

I switched to wechaty `padplus` puppet from the `wechaty-puppet-puppeteer` and found it stops more often than `wechaty-puppet-puppeteer`. I.e., `wechaty-puppet-puppeteer` normally stays up 10 times longer while padplus puppet logs me out ever two or three days.

**Update:**

To give clarification for Alfred's answer,

I don't think it is mainly because that my wechat account status is not good. I believe so because my bot has not interaction with wx server at all. I.e., it just sit there archiving all important messages that I received, saving them to files while filtering out the unimportant ones. So from the WX server point of view, there is no way for it to tell/judge whether my bot exist or not.

However, there is indeed one thing different, having switched to wechaty `padplus` puppet from the `wechaty-puppet-puppeteer`, is that I noticed whenever I sent a message for a new day, or when I haven't sent anything for quite a while, I will immediately get the following:

```xml
<sysmsg type="ClientCheckConsistency"><ClientCheckConsistency><clientcheck><fullpathfilename>@classes.dex</fullpathfilename><fileoffset>0</fileoffset><checkbuffersize>9999999</checkbuffersize><seq>536870912</seq></clientcheck></ClientCheckConsistency></sysmsg>
```

I don't know if it from the WX server or the `padplus` server, and I don't know how to satisfy such `ClientCheckConsistency`. I believe this is the main reason that my wechat account status is considered as not good by whatever server.

As the result, here what I get out of the box:

```
11:09:56 WARN Puppet constructor() watchdog.on(reset) reason: {"data":"9ee9935b-15db-442e-bfcb-5eff6396be7f","timeout":60000}
11:09:56 INFO PuppetPadplus stop()
11:09:56 INFO PuppetPadplus logout(true, logout in wechaty)
```

I.e.,

- almost all cases that padplus puppet logs me out is because of this Puppet constructor() watchdog timeout.
- I got `logout` as the default behavior out of the box, and my node js script just stops and quits, no Alfred's next step `PuppetPadplus start()`.

That is why I'm wondering if I can re-trigger the login (or restart) in logout event handling. Thx.

PPS. Today, I got logged out two times. Here is the log from last time:

```
15:46:53 VERB Unknown: <sysmsg type="ClientCheckConsistency"><ClientCheckConsistency><clientcheck><fullpathfilename>@classes.dex</fullpathfilename><fileoffset>0</fileoffset><checkbuffersize>9999999</checkbuffersize><seq>536870912</seq></clientcheck></ClientCheckConsistency></sysmsg> 
. . .
15:56:51 WARN Puppet constructor() watchdog.on(reset) reason: {"data":"710...c80","timeout":60000}
15:56:51 INFO PuppetPadplus stop()
15:56:51 INFO PuppetPadplus logout(true, logout in wechaty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think you'd better post an issue under the wechaty github repository

nah, I just want to get it over with. So finally I decided not to use something that I don't know and less reliable, but something that I know and very reliable:

```
while :; do node index.js; sleep 1m; done
```

Problem solved, for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is most likely because your wechat account status is not good.

There are some suggestion for you to make things better:

1. Consider to make your account stop using bot for few days (2-3 days or more).
2. It will be better to add a random delay to make reaction after your bot receive an event.
3. Throttling your actions if you have too many actions to make within a short period.

For more, if you want to get a callback when your bot is logged out, just note the `on.scan()` listener.

If the wechat account is logged during bot running, you may get the following lines of log:

> 00:25:55 INFO PuppetPadplus logout(true, 你已退出微信)
> 00:25:55 INFO PuppetPadplus stop()
> 00:25:55 INFO PuppetPadplus logout(true, logout in wechaty)
> 00:26:00 INFO PuppetPadplus start()

And the `scan` event will be triggered next, you can get the `qrcode` and `status` in the callback function, and then you can scan the qrcode to re-login manually.

Comment: I think you'd better post an issue under the wechaty github repository.

Comment: I don' t know if I can justify it as an issue, and I'm not sure it is padplus' propblem or  wechaty's ,as the wechaty-puppet-puppeteer had been working reliably for me for years, which can stay up 10 times longer than padplus. If you know better than me on this, please feel free to file an issue for me. thx Alfred.